# Calling a function from within v-bind:style doesn't trigger an update to the view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I have a list of images(like a gallery). A longpress(i'm using Nativescript-vue) on a picture will change the style of the image, and make it appear "selected". This is the image:

```
<ListView layout="grid" ref="backedupImages" for="image in sortedBackedupImages">
      <v-template>
        <ImageComponent
          v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:isSelected(image.identifier) ? 'cyan' : 'white'}"
          :onLongPress="()=>{onLongPress(image.identifier)}"
          :onShortPress="()=>{onShortPress(image.identifier)}"
          :image="image"
        ></ImageComponent>
      </v-template>
    </ListView>
```

As you can see, i'm calling some "isSelected" method, to check if the image is selected or not. The method sits in a mixin:

```
isSelected(identifier){            
            const isSelected = this.selectedImages.includes(identifier);
            return isSelected
        }
```

This is the onLongPress method, which toggles the image selection state:

```
onLongPress(identifier) {
            if(this.selectedImages.includes(identifier)){
                const index = this.selectedImages.indexOf(identifier);
                this.$delete(this.selectedImages,index);
            }else{
                const index = this.selectedImages.length;
                this.$set(this.selectedImages,index,identifier);
            }
        },
```

The array manipulation seems to work, but i do not get any view reactivity. What could be the problem? Is there a better approach for this in Vue? I don't think i can use a computed property, being that i need to pass an argument to the "computation".

Comment: I did review it, and therefore used the $set and $delete methods. Shouldn't it working now? Edit: I tried adding this line to the onLongPress function- no change.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I see that `$delete` should be working reactively. Have you reviewed the console for any errors?

Comment: I used tns debug android to foolow what'g going on, and it seems fine. Also, i used the vue dev-tools to see that the state changes, and it seems fine too. I will mention, that everything works if i scroll-down and scroll-up again(the ListView component is a virtualization component of Nativescript). But without the scrolling,  there is no reactivity.

Comment: It's absolutely essential that you mention that this is Nativescript and not pure Vue.js. That changes things considerably. Please read the following piece of [documentation](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/#an-important-note-about-v-for). It describes exactly your problem, which is a limitation of `v-template` inside of a `ListView` using `v-for`. It's a performance optimization feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that a `v-for` loop on `ListView` will not behave as expected. This issue is described in the [nativescript-vue documentation](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/#an-important-note-about-v-for):

> `<ListView>` does not loop through list items as you would expect when using a `v-for` loop. Instead `<ListView>` only creates the necessary views to display the currently visible items on the screen, and reuses the views that are already off-screen when scrolled. This concept is called view recycling and is commonly used in mobile apps to improve performance.
>
> This is important because you can't rely on event listeners attached inside the `v-template`. Instead, you need to use the `itemTap` event which contains the index of the tapped item and the actual item from the list.
>
> > onItemTap(event) {
> > console.log(event.index)
> > console.log(event.item)
> > }

Comment: Well, that seems to put a kink in my desired functionality, being that the itemTap event doesn't seem to distinguish between short tap and long tap...any idea? To be honest also, i doubt that this is really the issue here, being that i had no problem detecting the events "the normal way".

Comment: @sheff2k1 In that same documentation there's mention of a `refresh()` method. That could very well resolve the problem :) If this works, please let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly to reflect this.

Comment: Horrible documentation, i don't even understand how this refresh method is used. What exactly do i call it on? :D

Comment: Ok, an important update: I managed to get this thing working, by completely dropping the whole "selectedImages" array, and just appending a "selected" property to the image object. The problem is, i'm modifying a property on an object, received as a prop from the parent. It works now, but is this a source for bugs? In React this would never be done, there is always "one source of truth". How about Vue? Do you sometimes modify a prop from within the child?

Comment: You should never modify a prop. Instead, `watch` the prop for any changes, and on being changed create a copy to store in local data. This ensures that parent changes may still overwrite the child component's data, but that the child component's changes are limit to its own scope.

Comment: If you wanted to go the array route, apparently you add an `id` to the `ListView` and do `this.page.getViewById(“myListViewId”).refresh();`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194081/discussion-between-sheff2k1-and-b-fleming).